error while upgrading from ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04lts
when i open software updater app it says there is a new version available but when i press upgrade it says could not calculate upgrade.
The exact thing it says is this
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.


Are you sure that you haven't added an extra repo at some point ? Please update your question with the output of ˝sudo apt update˝

This is the output of the sudo apt update:

shrahbeel@shrahbeel-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

pls help me with this
